# R code: How can I filter X amount of elements after a string match?

Tags: r

I have a character string with multiple elements pulled from a pdf. I want to ONLY include 5 elements after a string match. So I have

```
c("Retail","Channel1","Discount","10/1/2019 20%","10/1/2020 20%","10/1/2021 20%",
  "Fee", "Channel1", "10/1/2019 $5","10/1/2020 5%","10/1/2021 5%"
  "Supply Chain", "Channel1","Discount", "10/1/2019 80%","10/1/2020 80%","10/1/2021 80%")
```

I want to detect "Retail" and then include up to the first "10/1/2021 20%"

Then I want to detect "Fee" and include up to "10/1/2021 5%"
Then "Supply Chain" and include up to "10/1/2021/ 80%"

The Retail, Fee, and Supply Chain will always be the same, but the date/percentage changes all the time.

Comment: Can you show the expected ouptut

Comment: We can use `tapply(v1, cumsum(v1 == "Retail"), head, 4)`  The description is not clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `tidyverse`:

```
v1 <- c("Retail", "Channel1", "Discount", "10/1/2019 20%", "10/1/2020 20%", 
"10/1/2021 20%", "Fee", "Channel1", "10/1/2019 $5", "10/1/2020 5%", 
"10/1/2021 5%", "Supply Chain", "Channel1", "Discount", "10/1/2019 80%", 
"10/1/2020 80%", "10/1/2021 80%")
```

Here we use `grepl` and `cumsum` to create a grouping variable for each string match. Then we select the top 5 rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(v1) %>% 
  mutate(tag = cumsum(grepl("Retail|Fee|Supply Chain", v1))) %>% 
  group_by(tag) %>% 
  top_n(5)

    Selecting by tag
# A tibble: 17 x 2
# Groups:   tag [3]
   v1              tag
   <fct>         <int>
 1 Retail            1
 2 Channel1          1
 3 Discount          1
 4 10/1/2019 20%     1
 5 10/1/2020 20%     1
 6 10/1/2021 20%     1
 7 Fee               2
 8 Channel1          2
 9 10/1/2019 $5      2
10 10/1/2020 5%      2
11 10/1/2021 5%      2
12 Supply Chain      3
13 Channel1          3
14 Discount          3
15 10/1/2019 80%     3
16 10/1/2020 80%     3
17 10/1/2021 80%     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option with `base R`

```
lapply(tapply(v1, cumsum(v1 %in%  c("Retail", "Fee", "Supply Chain")),
        head, 6), tail, -1)
#$`1`
#[1] "Channel1"      "Discount"      "10/1/2019 20%" "10/1/2020 20%" "10/1/2021 20%"

#$`2`
#[1] "Channel1"     "10/1/2019 $5" "10/1/2020 5%" "10/1/2021 5%"

#$`3`
#[1] "Channel1"      "Discount"      "10/1/2019 80%" "10/1/2020 80%" "10/1/2021 80%"
```

---

If this needs to include the 'Retail', 'Fee', 'Supply Chain' as well

```
tapply(v1, cumsum(v1 %in%  c("Retail", "Fee", "Supply Chain")), head, 6)
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("Retail", "Channel1", "Discount", "10/1/2019 20%", "10/1/2020 20%", 
"10/1/2021 20%", "Fee", "Channel1", "10/1/2019 $5", "10/1/2020 5%", 
"10/1/2021 5%", "Supply Chain", "Channel1", "Discount", "10/1/2019 80%", 
"10/1/2020 80%", "10/1/2021 80%")
```